# ValueError: Unexpected tuple '[' with StructType

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using the below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import json

def test(test1,test2):
    d = [{'amount': a, 'discount': t} for a, t in zip(test1, test2)]
    return d

arrayToMapUDF = udf(test, 
    ArrayType(
        StructType([
            StructField('amount', StringType()), 
            StructField('discount', StringType())
        ])
    )
)

df2 = df.withColumn("jsonarraycolumn", arrayToMapUDF(col("amount"), col("discount")))

df2.show(truncate=False)
```

But I'm getting this error:

> raise ValueError("Unexpected tuple %r with StructType" % obj)
> ValueError: Unexpected tuple '[' with StructType
>
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.handlePythonException(PythonRunner.scala:540)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonUDFRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonUDFRunner.scala:81)

When I do `df.printschme()` which is displaying fine. I am using spark version 2.4.5

```
+--------------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------
|        Name        |eligibility   |              amount                                         |           discount            |
+--------------------+--------------+------------------------------------------------------------+|-------------------------------|
|           product1|           Yes|[100, 1500, 2000, 3000, 3001]            |[0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05] |  
|            Product2|           Yes|[800, 3001,,,]                                            | [0.01, 0.02,,,]              |
+--------------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: could you please use `df.show(truncate=False)` ? the dataframe was truncated and it's impossible to see the data completely.

Comment: @mike sorry, I misunderstood your comment. however, per request, I posted in the question section.

Comment: Could you try replacing line 2 in the UDF with `d = [[a,t] for a, t in zip(test1, test2)]`?

Comment: @mike tried this option as well but getting the same error                                                  ```d = [[a,t] for a, t in zip(test1, test2)]```

Comment: I am confused. I cannot reproduce this error at all on Spark 2.4.5.

Comment: @mike null values are causing any issues?

Comment: possibly, I tested with nulls but it worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need UDF for this as you're using Spark 2.4+. You could simply use [arrays_zip](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#arrays_zip) function like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, arrays_zip
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, ArrayType


data = [
    ("product1", "Yes", [10000, 250000], [0.01, 0.02]),
    ("product2", "Yes", [80000, 300001], [0.01, 0.02])
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Name", "eligibility", "amount", "discount"])

schema = ArrayType(
    StructType([
        StructField('amount', StringType()),
        StructField('discount', StringType())
    ])
)
df = df.withColumn("jsonarraycolumn", arrays_zip(col("amount"), col("discount")).cast(schema))

df.show(truncate=False)

+--------+-----------+---------------+------------+-------------------------------+
|Name    |eligibility|amount         |discount    |jsonarraycolumn                |
+--------+-----------+---------------+------------+-------------------------------+
|product1|Yes        |[10000, 250000]|[0.01, 0.02]|[[10000, 0.01], [250000, 0.02]]|
|product2|Yes        |[80000, 300001]|[0.01, 0.02]|[[80000, 0.01], [300001, 0.02]]|
+--------+-----------+---------------+------------+-------------------------------+
```

Comment: ``` your code works perfectly thank you so much for valuable inputs and your efforts ```